# Touchpad Indicator doesn't disable the touchpad

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

Ubuntu 16.04 on
Dell 5770 laptop

I installed Touchpad Indicator as it was (and still is) very annoying to have the cursor move here and there and delete part of what I write.
I tweaked Touchpad Indicator to serve me as best it can. Unfortunately I selected "start hidden", and I can't see it anymore.
It's not working properly (it doesn't disable the touchpad as it should)

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file...

In `terminal`...

`gedit ~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf`

and change:

```
"start_hidden": true
```

to:

```
"start_hidden": false
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. (I voted for it, but since I have less than 15 points, my answer doesn't show up.)     I was able to edit the config file, and now I can view the icon on the top bar and change the preferences.

Comment: However, I had to use standard Ubuntu preferences to disable the touchpad.

Comment: @AlbertoVenturi I think that even with less than 15 rep, you could still click on the grey checkmark to accept. Maybe not? You may have touchpad-indicator configured incorrectly. Edit your question and include some screenshots of the various configuration options in the prefs and I'll take a look.